A doubt in the Sobolev space.
Sobolev space $H^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\left\{u\in \mathcal{S}': \mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+|\xi|^2)\widehat{u})\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\right\}$ (Wong definition in introduction pseudo differential operators)
If we define $H=\left\{u\in \mathcal{S}': \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u})\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\right\}$.
Does have sense this definition? I ask this because, in the first case, $(1+|\xi|^2)\widehat{u}\in \mathcal{S}'$ for all $u\in\mathcal{S}'$ because $(1+|\xi|^2)$ is a polynomial, but, $\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u}\not\in \mathcal{S}'$ (not necessarily
) if  only suppose that $u\in \mathcal{S}'$. But, if $u\in H$. Then  $\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u}$ have sense?

The definition of $H$ makes sense, although it is not written that clearly. The thing is that you need to assume that $\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u} \in \mathcal S’$ in order to apply the inverse Fourier transform. A way of making the definition of $H$ a bit more precise is thus the following:
$$ H=\left\{u\in \mathcal{S}': \mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u}\in\mathcal{S}’\text{ and }\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u})\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\right\}. $$

The condition $\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u}\in\mathcal S’$ is needed to make the definition 100% clear and formally correct. Whoever wrote the definition likely thought that the condition $\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u}\in\mathcal S’$ would be implicit in writing $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u})\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
Note also that the latter condition, even if does not make sense for any $u\in \mathcal S’$, is morally equivalent to
$$ \mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u}\in \mathcal F(L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)), $$
which indeed makes perfect sense for any $u\in \mathcal S’$. So the definition still makes a small abuse for the sake of conciseness, but the abuse is arguably not so serius and the gap can be easily filled by the reader.

This is not quite right: $e^{|x|^2}f$ need not be in $S'$ for $f$ to be a tempered distribution. There's just something (probably needlessly) garbled here...

@paulgarrett , I did not say that

Ok, sorry, I guess I'm just not understanding the role of $e^{|x|^2}$ here...

Maybe I was not that clear, hope it is better now.

@paul garrett But $\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}f$ is only required to be a tempered distribution for some (maybe for a really little many) tempered distributions.  Not for all.

I have a doubt. If $u\in H$ then $u$ is of the form $u=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(1/\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{f}\right)$ for some $f\in L^p$ or not? This implies that
$\widehat{u}=\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}} \widehat{f}$ and by replacing in the definition of $H$ then $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2} \widehat{u})=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}}\widehat{f})=f$ and alls done? Which means that perhaps assumption $\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u}\in\mathcal{S}'$ is unnecessary? I'm confused

@eraldcoil My point is: $\mathcal F^{-1}$ as an operator is only defined on $\mathcal S’$. So you need to assume $\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u}\in\mathcal S’$ even just to make sense of $\mathcal F^{-1} (\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u})$ :) Then, I agree with the things you wrote, but whether there is the need of assuming $\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u}\in\mathcal S’$ depends on how you write the definition, and to my personal opinion the definition that you reported in your post is not written in a correct way if you don’t add $\mathrm{e}^{|\xi|^2}\widehat{u}\in\mathcal S’$.

Oh now I think I understand. Thank you. If I have any other questions I will ask.
